How to resolve not a valid external type error in scala
I have newly started working in scala and I wrote below code to assert but it is failing to schema mismatch. I'm unable to figure out the reason behind it.
Below is the code I wrote -
object xyzz {
    val df = Seq(
    Row(10528.53994, 20232, "abc")
    )

}

val schema: StructType = StructType(
      Seq(
        StructField("AMOUNT", DoubleType),
        StructField("PERIOD", IntegerType),
        StructField("ID", StringType)
    )
)

val test = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(xyz.df), schema)

assert(
    test.where(col("ID") === lit("abc")).select(col("AMOUNT")).collect()(0) == 10528.53994
)

This is failing due to below error -
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 7, amount), DoubleType, false) AS AMOUNT#500610

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 14, period), IntegerType, false) AS PERIOD#500611

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 8, ID), StringType, false), true, false, true) AS ID#500612


Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Integer is not a valid external type for schema of double

Please help

please add spark versions and how you construct the spark session.  As with s.polam's answer there doesn't seem anything wrong with the fixed code (once your typo on xyzz.df is corrected).  It's quite possible you have mixed spark jar issues (e.g. you are either running it locally within an ide and bad versions or building against/shipping the wrong spark jars on a remote cluster)

This test.where(col("ID") === lit("abc")).select(col("AMOUNT")).collect()(0) will return object of org.apache.spark.sql.Row. Your assertion failed because this object is being compared with a Double value, as anticipated.
Change your code like below.
assert(test.where(col("ID") === lit("abc")).select(col("AMOUNT")).as[Double].collect.headOption.getOrElse(0D) == 10528.53994)


Still it is failing due to same error.

fyi - although the answer is not solving the problem it's still correct - your code should use the correct encoders, the ide / compiler also likely tells you the comparison is with unrelated types.

Not sure...it works for me on Jupyter notebook but not on Intellij IDE. Additionally, do I need to type cast the PERIOD column too even though I'm not selecting it?

Yes, you have to .. in above answer I have used amount column it's data type Double similarly .. you have to change same for all other columns.
